# Is there a way to make vscode show error warnings while working with react

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[Is there a way to make vscode show warnings while working with react as showen in the img below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o66Nh.png)

Comment: I think it is the eslint plugin

Comment: Thanks I will try then